# jQuery accordion split header

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to have a header of an accordion that has a split header.  By that I mean that I want to have the name on the left of the header, and the phone number on the right.  I have been struggling with this all morning, and I don't know why this will not work.  The variation that I thought would work based on what I have been reading on this topic is displayed in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bt_rox88/9w1o41df/6/). Any held would be appreciated.

```
<div class="accordion">   
    <h3 class="arrow-right">
        <span class="headerLeft">John Doe</span>
        <span class="headerRight">617-438-5000</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="accordion-body">Content 1</div>

    <h3 class="arrow-right">
        <span class="headerLeft">Jimmy James</span>
        <span class="headerRight">617-438-5001</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="accordion-body">Content 2</div>

    <h3 class="arrow-right">
        <span class="headerLeft">Johnny Johnson</span>
        <span class="headerRight">617-438-5002</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="accordion-body">Content 3</div>
</div>


jQuery(function ($) {

    $(".accordion").accordion({
        clearstyle: true,
        collapsible: true,
        active: 0
    }); 
    $(".accordion h3").click(function () {  
        //here want all non selected section to have a right arrow
        $(this).siblings("h3").removeClass("arrow-down");
        $(this).siblings("h3").addClass("arrow-right");   

        //here I want the selected section to have a down arrow
        $(this).toggleClass("arrow-right");
        $(this).toggleClass("arrow-down");   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your h3 needs to have a width. I set it to

```
.accordion h3 {
    width:400px;
}
```

as an example. Next is the span alignment. `text-align` only changes the text inside the elements. If you put it for span, the text in span will be aligned. If you want to align the element itself you should consider using `float`

```
.headerRight{
   float:right;
}

.headerLeft{
  float:left;
}
```

Put this together and you'll get like below (I have removed the JS since it was unnecessary here)

```css
.accordion h3 {
  width: 400px;
}
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
}
.accordion .accordion-body {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
}
.arrow-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}
.arrow-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid #f00;
}
.headerRight {
  float: right;
}
.headerLeft {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <h3 class="arrow-right">
        <span class="headerLeft">John Doe</span>
        <span class="headerRight">617-438-5000</span>
    </h3>
  <div class="accordion-body">Content 1</div>

  <h3 class="arrow-right">
        <span class="headerLeft">Jimmy James</span>
        <span class="headerRight">617-438-5001</span>
    </h3>
  <div class="accordion-body">Content 2</div>

  <h3 class="arrow-right">
        <span class="headerLeft">Johnny Johnson</span>
        <span class="headerRight">617-438-5002</span>
    </h3>
  <div class="accordion-body">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the one.  Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: Actually, I spoke too fast.  That get's me part of the way, but my red arrow gets messed up when increase the width.

Comment: Hmm I just realized the way you did the arrow. Unfortunately you cannot have both. You'll have to move the arrow in a separate element inside h3.

Answer (score 1):

Set the white-space to nowrap on the H3:

```
.accordion h3 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Full code below:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    
    $(".accordion").accordion({
        clearstyle: true,
        collapsible: true,
        active: 0
    }); 
    $(".accordion h3").click(function () {  
        //here want all non selected section to have a right arrow
        $(this).siblings("h3").removeClass("arrow-down");
        $(this).siblings("h3").addClass("arrow-right");   
        
        //here I want the selected section to have a down arrow
        $(this).toggleClass("arrow-right");
        $(this).toggleClass("arrow-down");   
    });
});
```

```css
.accordion h3 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.accordion {
    width: 100%;
}

.accordion .accordion-body {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    height: auto;
    display: none;
}
.arrow-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}
.arrow-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #f00;
}

.headerRight{
   text-align: right !important;
}

.headerLeft{
   text-align: left !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">   
    <h3 class="arrow-right">
        <span class="headerLeft">John Doe</span>
        <span class="headerRight">617-438-5000</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="accordion-body">Content 1</div>
    
    <h3 class="arrow-right">
        <span class="headerLeft">Jimmy James</span>
        <span class="headerRight">617-438-5001</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="accordion-body">Content 2</div>
   
    <h3 class="arrow-right">
        <span class="headerLeft">Johnny Johnson</span>
        <span class="headerRight">617-438-5002</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="accordion-body">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working because h3 is given arrow-right and it's toggling to arrow-down whose width is becoming 0.that's why it's coming down.So you have to separate arrow-right from h3 tag.
You can try this

HTML

```
<div class="accordion">   
    <h3>
        <span class="arrow-right"></span>
        <span class="arrow-down"></span>
        <span class="headerLeft">John Doe</span>
        <span class="headerRight">617-438-5000</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="accordion-body">Content 1</div>

    <h3>
        <span class="arrow-right"></span>
        <span class="arrow-down"></span>
        <span class="headerLeft">Jimmy James</span>
        <span class="headerRight">617-438-5001</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="accordion-body">Content 2</div>

    <h3>
        <span class="arrow-right"></span>
        <span class="arrow-down"></span>
        <span class="headerLeft">Johnny Johnson</span>
        <span class="headerRight">617-438-5002</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="accordion-body">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.accordion h3{
    background:#CCC;
}

.accordion {
    width: 100%;
    background:#f2f2f2;
}
.arrow-down {
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #f00;
}
.arrow-right {
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid #f00;
}

.headerRight{

    position:absolute;
    right:20px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:right;

}

.headerLeft{

    width:200px;
    position:relative;
    left:40px;
}
```

JQuery

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $(".arrow-down").hide();

    $(".accordion").accordion({
        clearstyle: true,
        collapsible: true,
        active: 0
    }); 
    $(".accordion h3").click(function () {  

        $(this).children('.arrow-right,.arrow-down').toggle();
        $(this).siblings().children('.arrow-down').hide();
        $(this).siblings().children('.arrow-right').show();

    });
});
```